# how to get the return value of findAndModify func in MongoDB with mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using Node.js+mongoose+MongoDB like this:

```
SomeModelSchema.statics.findAndModify = function (query, sort, doc, options, callback) {
    return this.collection.findAndModify(query, sort, doc, options, callback);
};

SomeModel.findAndModify({}, [], { $inc: { amount: 1 } }, {}, function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
});
```

I can increase the `amount` successfully but I want to get the new value of `amount` without doing the query again. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Specify `{new:true}` in the `options` object. This will cause the result value of `findAndModify` to be the document after the update is applied, which you can then read from to get the new value of `amount`.

Details here, in the table: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/findAndModify+Command

I believe your callback will need to take two arguments, like:
`function(err, result){`

When the callback is fired, `result` should contain the new document (if `err` is null).

Answer (score 2):

I checked monk's source code and finally made this working. Even [code documentation](https://github.com/Automattic/monk/blob/1.0.0/lib/collection.js#L229) says how it should be, but it is not visible from [documentation](https://github.com/Automattic/monk#and-modify) on monk's web.

```
/**
 * findAndModify
 *
 * @param {Object} search query, or { query, update } object
 * @param {Object} optional, update object
 * @param {Object|String|Array} optional, options or fields
 * @param {Function} callback
 * @return {Promise}
 * @api public
 */
```

It means you can either specify *query* and *update* as separate parameters, plus *options* as third parameter:

```
notescollection.findAndModify(
  { "_id": id },
  { "$set": { 
      "title": title,
      "content": content
  }},
  { "new": true, "upsert": true },
  function(err,doc) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log( doc );
  }
);
```

Or you can specify *query* and *update* as fields of first parameter, plus *options* as second parameter:

```
notescollection.findAndModify(
  {
    "query": { "_id": id },
    "update": { "$set": { 
        "title": title,
        "content": content
    }}
  },
  { "new": true, "upsert": true },
  function(err,doc) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log( doc );
  }
);
```

For more on the sources check [findAndModify](https://github.com/Automattic/monk/blob/1.0.0/lib/collection.js#L254) function in collections.js file.