# mongodb mongoose js update not inserting new field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to insert a new field 'description' with a findOneAndUpdate statement using Mongoose js. It is not working. The code works fine when the field already exists and updates it with the given value. According to the Mongodb documentation 
$set should create this field automatically if it does not exist.

Any ideas appreciated.

```
Course.findOneAndUpdate({'_id': CourseId},{$set:{'description':courseDescription}},function(err, course) {
        if (err)
            res.jsonp({response:'err'});

        res.jsonp(course);
    });
```

Comment: Look at the "options" in the documentation for "new".

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get the return value of findAndModify func in MongoDB with mongoose?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9773684/how-to-get-the-return-value-of-findandmodify-func-in-mongodb-with-mongoose)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With mongoose you cannot set arbitrary fields, at least not in the way your trying to in your example.

You need to add the description to your `Course` Schema and then your code example will work.

Comment: I actuallly thought I had this field defined in my schema. When I double checked, I noticed it was not there at all. Thanks

Comment: Wow what a simple but dumb mistake, thanks anyway!

Comment: @real_ate, @noobie @jarret I faced a very weird behavior from the mongoose. Even I defined the new fields in the schema and `ModelName.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { $set: { desc: 'val' } }, { new: true, lean: true })` but it does not work. The generated mongodb query has no `desc` field. IDK what is wrong. Do you have any thought?

Comment: you should double-check your schema, the point of this answer is that if you don't have things updating then it's likely that your schema is missing something